# MySQL: Order by 2nd column--if not null--while maintaining 1st column order

Tags: php, mysql, database

Essentially I want to order by "title", while grouping movies with the same, non-NULL "series_id" together within that order. Titles where series_id IS NULL should order by title only, while non NULL series_ids should order by "series_order" and be listed in the results based on "series"."title" within the original columns sort. I would prefer to achieve this within the query rather then loading the entire database and sorting from there.

What I have tried (MySQL 5.7.17):

**ORDER BY title, series_id**

```
    SELECT * FROM media
        ORDER BY title, series_id, series_order
    LIMIT 0, 30
```

Does not account for titles in a series that are not alphabetically the same (see sample below).

**ORDER BY CASE using CONCAT to sort by 'series'.'title' + 'media'.'series_order'**

```
    SELECT * FROM media
        ORDER BY CASE
            WHEN series_id IS NULL THEN title
            ELSE CONCAT((SELECT title FROM series WHERE id = media.series_id), series_order)
        END
    LIMIT 0, 30
```

Th results are correctly ordered in a SQL Fiddle, but not on the dev server. To be fair this is still not the desired result as the 'series'.'title' may differ from the original movies title.

**LEFT JOIN to include the 'series' table for sorting using the same idea**

```
    SELECT media.*, series.title, series.id FROM media
        LEFT JOIN series ON media.series_id = series.id
    LIMIT 0, 30
```

This does not order the data correctly, either.

**Sample Data**:

| title | series_id | series_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 88 Minutes | NULL | NULL |
| Live Free or Die Hard | 100094 | 4 |
| 3rd Rock from the Sun | 100000 | 2 |
| 2 Guns | NULL | NULL |
| Die Hard | 100094 | 1 |
| Evil Dead | NULL | NULL |
| A Good Day to Die Hard | 100094 | 5 |
| 3rd Rock from the Sun | 100000 | 1 |

| Desired Result | Order |
| --- | --- |
| 2 Guns | NULL |
| 3rd Rock from the Sun | 1 |
| 3rd Rock from the Sun | 2 |
| 88 Minutes | NULL |
| Die Hard | 1 |
| Live Free or Die Hard | 4 |
| A Good Day to Die Hard | 5 |
| Evil Dead | NULL |

**Primary Table**: media
**Relevant Columns**: *title, series_id, series_order*

**Series Table**: series
**Relevant Columns**: *id, title*

**Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efca7c/3

On the fiddle, option 2 appears to be working. On the dev version it only partially orders things.

**EDIT**: As it turns out the PHP code I was using to store the data before converting it to JSON was inevitably re-ordering the results by the Primary ID.

Comment: Your `media` table is missing `id` column. Is it a primary key?

Comment: So you're actually looking at the web interface ordering and not the result from the query? If I'm not mistaken, the order you place in query does not necessarily get replicated on the web interface... it's two different ordering. Query running behind should already _limit_ the results based on filters being placed and I'm pretty sure it won't load the entire database. Then you should try to figure out the ordering from the web interface, right?

Comment: @FaNo_FN The web interface is doing an AJAX request which is then returned in JSON. The order is not being modified by the interface as I haven't written any ordering into the interface yet.

Comment: So, let's say we work with a small set of data like before, then you've manage to get the order right in query but when it translate to the web interface, the order changed. I'm assuming that the final JSON value is being retrieved into the web is according to the ordering IN the JSON, correct? I suppose you'll be able to see if the conversion from MySQL query to JSON retain the same ordering. Sorry I'm not _really_ familiar with AJAX or JSON but it seems like this is not a MySQL query issue.

Comment: @FaNo_FN You were on the mark BTW. While it wasn't the AJAX or JSON that was the problem, I was storing the information in a PHP variable in a way that automatically sorted it by the Primary ID. The results were only fluctuating when results were removed based on my search params. I thumbed up your comments as they were relevant in finding a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the required convolution to achieve your desired sorting, if this was my application, I'd probably create a new column which contains the "base title" for the series and populate that value during insertion, then you could sort on that without any voodoo or eye-strain.

In the absence of modifying your table structure, I managed to downgrade a solution that was using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION` ([MySQL8.0 Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab1e3d0fd0e29f23994d6ee6839e929c)) into a couple of nested subqueries -- it's not what I consider beautiful.

SQL ([Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efca7c/15))

```
SELECT m2.title grouping_title, m1.title, COALESCE(m2.title, m1.title), m1.series_order
FROM media m1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT series_id, title
    FROM media m3
    WHERE series_order = (SELECT MIN(series_order) FROM media WHERE series_id = m3.series_id)
) m2 ON m1.series_id = m2.series_id
ORDER BY COALESCE(m2.title, m1.title), m1.series_order
```

You can modify the outer `SELECT` as you wish, but I just wanted to show what the `COALESCE()` function was generating.  Effectively, I'm joining media table onto itself so that I can obtain the lowest `series_order` value for a given `series_id`.  The `title` in the THAT row represents the "base title" to be used in the first rule of the sorting algorithm -- unless it is `NULL`, in which case, we just use the `title` from the parent query.

For your application output, you will want to use the `m1.title` and the `m1.series_order`.

Comment: My bad man. Here is where I admit to being a complete moron. This entire time I haven't been paying attention to the fact that I have been storing everything into $Movies[$ID] which will... dun dun dun... order it by primary_id when converted to JSON. I should be storing it based on sql's original order. Ugh! I am sorry I wasted your time. Going to mark your answer as the best one though. You definitely spent the time coming up with a working solution! (To be fair, the sql was not working before I posted this question at least). *queue face palm*

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression to check whether seris_order value is null, if it is null then take only titlw, otherwise concatenate title with the series_order.

**Query**

```
Select case when series_order is null then title else concat(title, ' : Season ', series_order) end as title
From table_name
Order by 1;
```

Comment: Okay, this got me closer to what I'm looking for but I'm still not getting the desired result. Your suggestion was resulting in all non-null series_order's being placed at the end of results. I used the CASE idea and got here: `SELECT * FROM media ORDER BY CASE WHEN series_id IS NULL THEN title ELSE CONCAT((SELECT title FROM series WHERE id = media.series_id), series_order) END` The result in pretty much the same as I originally was getting, but I feel it's almost there. I tried a left join as well to use the 'series'.'title' column to sort, but it put all series_id's up front.

Comment: @TibTibs , you should update your question regarding the _"non-null being placed at the end"_. And as far as I can tell, this query suggestion returns [exactly as the desired result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=20b60bc4cdd939ef01f60d28c6be905d) you've posted in your question. Can you provide more details on that? I mean do you have a different desired result after you've tested this query?

Comment: For the reason stated by @FaN, this page should be closed as Needs Clarification.